# Synchronization problem in functions of Javascript

Tags: javascript, synchronization

I am developing an application,In that application i have many functions that return us server data.. I have 40 function that needs to be executed 1 by 1 for synchronization to take place.SO i have taken a single function and placed my 40 functions in it... Now the problem is that some of these function skip performing database operations

My one out of 40 function to perform this is

```
function sync_down_client_info(){
    try {

            parent.parent.parent.stmt_select.text = "select query";
            parent.parent.parent.stmt_select.execute();
            parent.parent.parent.result = parent.parent.parent.stmt_select.getResult();
            if (parent.parent.parent.result.data != null) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < parent.parent.parent.result.data.length; i++) {

                            var admin_id = parent.parent.parent.admin_id;
                            var sync_client_date =  parent.parent.parent.result.data[i].last_sync_client;
                            // alert(admin_id+"======="+ sync_client_date);

                            GATEWAY = 'http://projects/one_acc/flashservices/gateway.php';
                            conn = new parent.parent.parent.air.NetConnection();
                            conn.connect(GATEWAY); 

            response = new parent.parent.parent.air.Responder(clientresult, clientFault);
                            conn.call('down_client_info', response,admin_id,sync_client_date);


                            response = new parent.parent.parent.air.Responder(clientserverdatetimeResult, clientserverdatetimeFault);
                            conn.call('check_datetime', response);

                    }
            };
```

and clientresult function is

```
function  clientresult(e)
     {

    for (var i=0; i<e.length; i++) {
            //alert(e.length);
            parent.parent.parent.stmt_select.text="select query ;
            parent.parent.parent.stmt_select.execute();
            parent.parent.parent.result = parent.parent.parent.stmt_select.getResult();
            if(parent.parent.parent.result.data!=null){


              parent.parent.parent.stmt_insert.text= "update client_info ;
                      parent.parent.parent.stmt_insert.execute();
            }
```

can anyone tell me how to do this syncing?

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking so I can't advise you on that, but looking at your code: what's with all the `parent.parent.parent.xyz'`? You can pretty it up (and probably speed it up) if you add `var ggp = parent.parent.parent;` at the top of your function (or perhaps pass parent.parent.parent in as a parameter) and then just say `ggp.xyz` everywhere. (In case it's not obvious I used 'ggp' for 'great-grandparent'.)

Comment: Actually i have a lot of functions that execute this clientresult function which contains queries...so when i execute those functions in a bunch then some of them miss the queries that they need to execute.. they work fine when i use them in a single function but when i use them in bunch of 4 or 5 then i dont know y the system miss some queries.... is there any way to know how my function like sync_down_client_info performs exections of operations ,so that i can place my other function after it

Comment: When you say "a lot of functions that execute this clientresult function" do you mean they all have that same function as part of a callback from the NetConnection/Responder stuff. I'm not familiar with NetConnection/Responder but if it is doing something asynchronously and then returning via a callback I would not be surprised if some of the responses go astray if you do 40 at once, let alone 40 all to the same callback. When you say "some of them miss the queries that they need to execute" have you confirmed that it is even getting to the function each time?

Comment: Actually a lot of functions involves modules of the application and i have compiled it in one syncchronization function acording to my needs... And yes it goes inside each function but doesnt execute queries for each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery has constructs like the AjaxQueue to avoid these race conditions you are seeing. I'd advise using these plugins.

Refer http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ajaxqueue